# AWS CDK test template and avoid creating docker images

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I want to test an AWS CDK construct/template that involves creating a lambda function with a docker image asset. This causes the unit tests to take awhile to execute. Is there anyway to tell the cdk to not physically create these docker images for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got esbuild installed? Without access to esbuild the bundling part of generating the lambda falls back to docker.